# Why can I not use special unicode characters in my html?

Tags: angular

I'm working from a mock my designer did and as a placeholder until we have an image to use we have `[ &Congruent; ]` to indicate a drag handle which renders as [ ≡ ]. This works fine int he straight HTML mock-up but when I use it in the actual Angular app I'm building I get an error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Unknown entity "Congruent"

I get the Angular isn't going to know what Congruent is, but it doesn't need to, why is it trying to do anything to my text node? Does the ampersand mean something to Angular? If so, can I escape it?

I thought it might be the brackets, but removing them gives me the same error, and I tried adding ng-non-bindable to the element, but it didn't change anything either.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/compiler/src/ml_parser/tags.ts#L57 Because `Congruent ` is not whitelisted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, specific names for entities (i.e. text content in the form `&name;`) are whitelisted by the Angular template parser: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/compiler/src/ml_parser/tags.ts#L57

As noted in the comments there:

```ts
// This list is not exhaustive to keep the compiler footprint low.
// The `&#123;` / `&#x1ab;` syntax should be used when the named character reference does not exist.
```

However, while `Congruent` isn't whitelisted, note that `equiv`, which refers to the same `≡` character, *is*. Just use:

```html
[ &equiv; ]
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why we are dependent on a white list for these? Why does the template parser care what I'm using in a text node?

Comment: @invertedSpear not sure, you'd have to look at how that list gets used.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the hex or decimal notation instead: `&#x02261;` or `&#8801;`. I found those here: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref.